# What are the calculations required to design transmission system for an Electric Kart ( i.e Go Kart)?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

There is a national level competition **Ecokart** (Electric kart design & manufacturing) has been held every year in Delhi, India. there are some rules for making the kart which are specified in the rule book.

[ECO KART SERIES](http://www.ecokart.in/index.html)

Comment: Give more detail : top speed, motor speed, wheel diameter etc, then gear ratio - driven to driver is explained in most mechanics books.

Comment: thank you for your reply,  i was able to upload two images of rules for building Kart , I am new user of  https://engineering.stackexchange.com , ( joined 1 day before  your reply ) hence facing difficulties in using stack exchange , I will try to give more specifications soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple calculation which will give you a single correct answer as gear ratios are essentially an optimisation problem. A higher final drive ratio will give a higher top speed (up to a point at least) while a lower ratio will give you more torque (although usable torque is also limited by the traction of the drive wheels.

The overall approach for designing something like this is to start with fairly simple calculations based on reasonable approximations to work out rough orders of magnitude and where the limits are and then progressively refine your numbers as you get closer to what a sensible design should look like.

It is also helpful to look at existing real world examples to get a sense of what is likely to be possible.

The diameter of the wheels and tyres will affect the final drive ratio too so you may want to look at what wheels you are using first.

Th basic concept of [gear ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear_train) is simple enough and similarly for every turn of the road wheels you move forwards by the circumference of the wheel.

eg. if you have a wheel with circumference of 0.6m turning @ 600 rpm (ie 10 revolutions per second the road speed is 0.6m * 10/s = 6m/s or about 13.4mph

Answer (score 1):

To begin, you need to ask yourself the requirements.  Here's a short list to begin:

- Manual or Automatic?  If automatic, how will you automate it?
- Top speed?
- Maximum incline at top speed?
- Maximum weight
- Maximum dimensions
- Motor characteristics.  Most DC motors have a maximum torque and maximum speed, and follow a roughly triangular load curve.  These details ensure you can hit all the load points
- Availability.  If you're building this yourself, the world is your oyster.  If you're buying it, you're settling on some off-the shelf options.  What do you have available from suppliers?

Comment: thank you for your reply,  i was able to upload two images of rules for building Kart , I am new user of  https://engineering.stackexchange.com , ( joined 1 day before  your reply ) hence facing difficulties in using stack exchange , I will try to give more specifications soon